# Could below zero decibel environment cause arrhythmia?

Tags: cardiology, reflexes

While this topic has virtually no real life application and has never been examined due to obvious reasons, it is quite intriguing to me.

I've read a lot of speculations and claims about the world's quietest room (-8.7 decibel at Orfield Laboratories in South Mineapolis) including loss/deterioration of hearing, hallucinations etc. What I was wondering about is if any of the human self-preservance reflexes would kick in once an individual hears his own bodily fluids and organs expanding/retracting? Since, as far as I know, there aren't any scientific proofs or thesis on this subject, what are your thoughts based on your knowledge on regular body functions and reflexes?

Third-party links: [TheDailySwarm's post](http://www.thedailyswarm.com/headlines/worlds-quietest-room-breeds-insanity/), [CBC's post](http://www.cbc.ca/strombo/news/the-sound-of-silence-a.html), [Quora's post](http://awesomefacts.quora.com/The-Worlds-Quietest-room-can-drive-you-crazy)

Comment: Can you include a reference to the speculations and claims that you've read? This makes it easier for others to fill in.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "self-preservance reflexes"?

Comment: @MCM I was thinking of the involuntary actions a body makes when it detects a danger (e.g. removing extremities from a heated surface, increasing blood circulation to preserve BT in cold environment) so I was wondering if hearing your own heart-beat would cause your body to classify it as endangered state and try to adjust the pulse which could cause arrhythmia.

Comment: This question is better suited for skeptics SE.. As far as I understand, lack of auditory stimulus shouldn't interfere with any visceral function. People might feel depressed and heart may react to the psychological state but there cannot be any *reflex* here

Comment: @WYSIWYG I think its on-topic here as well - if there are potential effects and mechanisms they are clearly within the field of biology.

Comment: But the problem is, like I wrote in the question, that there exists no research on this topic, so any discussion would be pure speculation.

Comment: Since we are used to hearing sound it would not be very pleasant to be in complete silence. Hearing has not evolved to report the somatic state, but to merely perceive the environment. So my best guess is that this effect (if it exists) is purely psychological.

Comment: What makes you think that ".. an individual can hear his own bodily fluids and organs expanding/retracting"? in silence?